# Complicated Join Query, Join 3 tables with multiple group bys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

#### Tweets:

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
    text_content    VARCHAR(280) not null,
    username        VARCHAR(50) not null,
    timestamp       TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    id              UUID not null DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    CONSTRAINT      tweets_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

#### Likes:

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
    username        VARCHAR(50) not null,
    timestamp       TIMESTAMP not null default current_timestamp,
    post_id         UUID not null,
    CONSTRAINT      likes_pk PRIMARY KEY (username, post_id),
    CONSTRAINT      likes_post_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES tweets(id)
);
```

#### And Retweets

```
CREATE TABLE retweets (
    username        VARCHAR(50) not null,
    timestamp       TIMESTAMP not null default current_timestamp,
    post_id         UUID not null,
    CONSTRAINT      retweets_pk PRIMARY KEY (username, post_id),
    CONSTRAINT      retweets_post_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES tweets(id)
);
```

I need a query, that would select all tweets, along with the amount of likes and retweets they have.
I did manage to write a working query, but I think I over-complicated it, and would love to hear simpler solutions!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Please post your code, it can be a useful starting point to help you in improving your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to aggregate *before* joining.  Assuming the `join` key is `post_id`:

```
select t.*, l.likes, r.retweets
from tweets t left join
     (select post_id, count(*) as likes
      from likes
      group by post_id
     ) l
     on l.post_id = t.id left join
     (select post_id, count(*) as retweets
      from retweets
      group by post_id
     ) r
     on r.post_id = t.id;
```